# Overload Javadoc in inheriting class

Tags: java, javadoc

I have following functional hierarchy which I'm recreating in Java:

```
   Diagram
     |
     |--Model
          |
          |--Entity
```

All those object share some common properties (id, name) and also an reference to parent object in hierarchy. So I have implemented an abstract class:

```
abstract class DBObject{
   private final int id;
   private final String name;
   private final DBObject parent;

   //constructors, getters, setters here

   /**
    * @return reference to parent object in hierarchy.
    */
    public final getParent(){
       return parent;
    }
}
```

So far no problem. The thing is, that Diagram has no parent and will always return null. This is ensured by implementation. But I would like to reflect the "parent always null" in Diagram Javadoc.
Is it possible to overload Javadoc, without overriding method? Solution would be to state that in abstract class as a note, but that's no an answer I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: You could state it in the javadoc of the constructor (which takes no parent, whereas the other kinds of DBObject take one, and/or in the javadoc of the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
/**
* @return reference to parent object in hierarchy. may be null.
*/
@Nullable
public final DBObject getParent(){
   return parent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace the Javadoc you have to override the method in the child class.

E.g.

Iterator.iterator() is overridden in 
   Collection.iterator() which is overridden by 
   Set.iterator() which is overridden by 
   NavigableSet.iterator() just to give each a different Javadoc.